# Blackberry web services

Tags: json, web-services, rest, blackberry, service

I am looking to expose an existing app as web service for use on the Blackberry.  So I have some questions around the blackbery and its use of web services.

I am wonderings is it possible to use Restful web services (using JSON as the payload) on the blackbery or is SOAP the only web services the balckbery can do?

In recent times I have used the Jersey framework for web services in normal web apps and I think this would suit my current requirements,just need to know if this is possible on the blackberry. Effectively the blackbery would only need to send/recive/procees HTTP calls and JSON so I would imagine this would be possible?

Also I may have to use the enterprise blackberry server, how do I route requests to/from the app (and the enterprise server) to the back end existing app. Is this all seamless with some config settings on the enterprise server or does the the blackberry application need to handle this in a certain way?

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use a RESTful service and JSON on the BlackBerry. Depending on the version you are targeting you may have to [download a JSON library](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/). There is also a good reference guide at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/json-me/ you can look through.

The Enterprise server shouldn't affect your ability to use this, as you're essentially making the same calls a browser would, and it will know how to route that traffic.